# MVC sequence diagram review

Tags: model-view-controller, uml, sequence-diagram, plantuml

*My first suggestion was that such questions fit better for CodeReview site. But there's no `uml` tag on CodeReview. Hope it's fine to post it here.*

Here's my first ever sequence diagram. It describes the execution of MVC (CLI) application.

- `View` – obviously stands for a view component of MVC approach
- `Application` – a controller class
- `Command` – an abstract base class and its derivatives
- `model` – a bunch of dataclasses
- `Persistence Manager` – a class for DB and file-system operations

Are UML notation and logic used correctly? Please, give me some comments on it.

[image: MVC app sequence diagram]

Diagram is generated with PlantUML: [code](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ByZyl0ofTmm0Jg).

[Light-themed image](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/QQAJhKyX6wnECw).

Comment: Would you mind to provide a black on white rather than gray on gray version?

Comment: **@qwerty_so**, this version corresponds SO dark theme, that`s why I chose it. Please find new URL to diagram render in classic PlantUML theme

Comment: I don't care. 99% of all dark themes I've seen are simply not readable. Same goes for your diagram. I will not worsen my already bad eyes by finding the lifellines dark gray on not so dark gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good so far.

There are some minor notation errors. This is how it should be:

- create messages are dashed (messages ending in the head of a lifeline)
- synchroneous messages have a filled trianglular arrow head (messages that preceed a dashed reply message)

I find it strange that the loop condition has the same name as the operation `maincycle`. Also the condition needs to be observed by the *sender* of the *first* message in the fragment. This is the user.

The user doesn't have a way to know, that it is ok to send the command. Maybe a feedback is needed, that the view has been created.

If the user starts the loop, probably she should also be able to end it.

Of course, a sequence diagram is usually incomplete and only shows *one* possible sequence. Therefore, it might well be ok as it is.

Comment: **@Axel**, thanks for your feedback! I haven't known that it is a loop condition, I have thought it's just loop name )) As for arrow heads – it is PlantUML who renders this form for synchroneous messages. Asynchroneous it renders with only lines. Take a glance, please, at [this version](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/xLMmxtptderEAw), if I get your points right?